# Strange MTU value from ping

Tags: networking

I am trying to make on-line steam games work on my laptop. I have this problem: games can't connect to game servers if I run them on linux. If I run them on Windows they work fine. Other Windows laptop on this network works fine too. If I run the game on linux but on another network it works fine too.

Currently I think that MTU is the problem.

```
$ ip link list
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 68:f7:28:24:00:3f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:d1:b8:76:05:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff


$ ping -M do -s 700 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 700(728) bytes of data.
ping: local error: Message too long, mtu=576
ping: local error: Message too long, mtu=576
ping: local error: Message too long, mtu=576
^C
--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2004ms
```

My question is why does the `ping` say `mtu=576`?
From `ip link list` we can see that `wlp3s0` has `mtu 1500`. Also, I've set router's MTU to 1492 according to ISP's information.

**UPD**. I've found out that `576   Typically recommended as the MTU for dial-up type applications, leaving 536 bytes of TCP data.`

**UPD 2**
`192.168.0.108` is my IP, `192.168.0.1` is my router's IP.

```
$ ip route show
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp3s0  src 192.168.0.108  metric 303  mtu 576
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp3s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.108  metric 303  mtu 576
```

**UPD 3** I've also tried to do `ping google.com -f -l 1480` on a Windows 10 laptop in the same network. It worked as it should. Lengths less than ~1500 pass and more than ~1500 need fragmenting. So, the problem is on my end.

Comment: Maybe we should move this to Superuser?

Comment: add `ip route show` output to your question please

Comment: @Serge oh there is `mtu 576` too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my first time with `ip route` but I did this:

`ip route del` all routes and then

```
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp3s0 mtu 1492
```

to add a default route through my router. I hope I didn't miss anything important.

Comment: Better check the settings at your router: if it provides the IP settings to your host by means of DHCP then there is some reason for such MTU.

Comment: I've set 1492 at my router according to ISP's instructions. I am using ADSL connection. Also, games are working great, so I think everything should be good.